# php str_replace() string to array error

Tags: php, arrays

```
str_replace($search, $replace, $subject);
```

I have no problem with $search string and $replace string.

But how can I use `str_replace()` with $search string and $replace array?

Comment: What do you mean `$search string and $replace array?` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`str_replace()` documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) provides a clear example how to use arrays (of equal size):

```
// Provides: You should eat pizza, beer, and ice cream every day
$phrase  = "You should eat fruits, vegetables, and fiber every day.";
$healthy = array("fruits", "vegetables", "fiber");
$yummy   = array("pizza", "beer", "ice cream");

$newphrase = str_replace($healthy, $yummy, $phrase);
```

Using `$search` as a string and `$replaces` as an array is not possible and 'weird': which array value should be used for matches?

Comment: Thanks, I got what you meant